# X3501 'main entrypoint not found'

Tags: visual-studio, game-engine, directx-11, hlsl

I am having a really hard time trying to compile some shaders for a Direct X 11 tutorial I am working my way through.

For some reason, even when I explicitly change the "Entrypoint name" I am still getting this message. **X3501 'main entrypoint not found'**

I want to be able to compile the shaders during build time as opposed to run time.

Here is a screenshot of the hlsl properties for my Vertex Shader:

[image]

and here is the Vertex Shader code:

```
 cbuffer cbPerObject : register(b0)
 {
     float4x4 gWorldViewProj; 
 };

 struct VertexIn
 {
     float3 PosL  : SV_POSITION;
     float4 Color : COLOR;
 };

 struct VertexOut
 {
     float4 PosH  : SV_POSITION;
     float4 Color : COLOR;
 };

 VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
 {
     VertexOut vout;

     // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
     vout.PosH = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);

     // Just pass vertex color into the pixel shader.
     vout.Color = vin.Color;

     return vout;
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I also have the similar setup for my pixel shader as well

Answer (score 2):

You should select "All Configurations" and "All Platforms". Otherwise you are only setting it up correctly for Debug/x64.

Comment: This still didn't work. I updated my Visual studio to 2017 version and now the shaders seem to be working. Thanks for the help Chuck.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the hlsl file from your project but not delete.The visual studio should not compile the hlsl file.It doesn`t matter main entry point,so edit the name of entry point is useless.